# Rails cant find record by sha1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model

```
after_create :generate_token
def generate_token
  self.token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s + self.id.to_s)
  self.save
end
```

When I trying

```
Model.find_by_token(params[:token])
```

returned nil.

But if I make

```
@t = Model.last
@t.token = "ec088e7de0c1e25997f1a2e417c9b9bd150ea7a0"
@t.save
```

And I can find this record by

```
Model.find_by_token(params[:token])
```

where `params[:token]` is `"ec088e7de0c1e25997f1a2e417c9b9bd150ea7a0"`

Also it works when simple

```
def generate_token
  self.token = rand(100).to_s + self.id.to_s
  self.save
end
```

Comment: What is the saved token? what is is `params[:token]`? does it exist in the database?

Comment: If I look `Model.all ` I see right tokens. also params[:token] is right

Comment: So you are saying the `Model.find_by_token` is not working properly?

Comment: `Model.find_by_token` do not work it return nil, if token is fielded by `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest`

Comment: can u show me the console query? when retrieving by find_by_token

Comment: [console](http://imgur.com/VQztWWB)

Comment: You should find out how to copy text out of your console, looking at a picture is not helpful when you want to compare two long random-looking text strings.

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6QGQCkm4)

Comment: In your console what happens if you do `the_token = Task.first.token` then `Task.find_by_token(the_token)`?

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gK77nLRa)

Comment: Wierd; that's proved there is no copy/paste problem.  Can you do the query directly to the database i.e. not through the rails console?  Which database are you using?  I have a table in MySQL with SHA256 used to generate one field and I can successfully use a dynamic find_by method.

Comment: I use default db sqlite [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mU5JAR7h) I think it is problem with db

Comment: Well, I find some information about this problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlite3-ruby/40GmnmULOCQ)